# How to make density plot correctly show area near the limits?

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

When I plot densities with ggplot, it seems to be very wrong around the limits. I see that `geom_density` and other functions allow specifying various density kernels, but none of them seem to fix the issue.

How do you correctly plot densities around the limits with ggplot?

---

As an example, let's plot the Chi-square distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. Using the builtin probability densities:

```
library(ggplot2)

u = seq(0, 2, by=0.01)
v = dchisq(u, df=2)

df = data.frame(x=u, p=v)

p = ggplot(df) +
    geom_line(aes(x=x, y=p), size=1) +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 2), ylim=c(0, 0.5))

show(p)
```

We get the expected plot:

[image]

Now let's try simulating it and plotting the empirical distribution:

```
library(ggplot2)

u = rchisq(10000, df=2)

df = data.frame(x=u)

p = ggplot(df) +
    geom_density(aes(x=x)) +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 2))

show(p)
```

We get an incorrect plot:

[image]

We can try to visualize the actual distribution:

```
library(ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr)

u = rchisq(10000, df=2)

df = data.frame(x=u)

p = ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x=x, y=0.5), position=position_jitter(height=0.2), shape='.', alpha=1) +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 2), ylim=c(0, 1))

show(p)
```

And it seems to look correct, contrary to the density plot:

[image]

It seems like the problem has to do with kernels, and `geom_density` does allow using different kernels. But they don't really correct the limit problem. For example, the code above with `triangular` looks about the same:

[image]

Here's an idea of what I'm *expecting to see* (of course, I want a density, not a histogram):

```
library(ggplot2)

u = rchisq(10000, df=2)

df = data.frame(x=u)

p = ggplot(df) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=x), center=0.1, binwidth=0.2, fill='white', color='black') +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 2))

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your use of `geom_violin` - it's usually used where you would use a boxplot, e.g. showing the distribution across multiple discrete categories. When I run the code I also get something that looks different to the image you posted.

Comment: @Marius I just pasted the wrong code by mistake, man. No need for the stats lecture.

Answer (score 2):

The usual kernel density methods have trouble when there is a constraint such as in this case for a density with only support above zero. The usual recommendation for handling this has been to use the logspline package:

```
install.packages("logspline")
library(logspline)
png(); fit <- logspline(rchisq(10000, 3))       
plot(fit) ; dev.off()
```

[image]

If this needed to be done in the ggplot2 environment there is a dlogspline function:

```
densdf <- data.frame( y=dlogspline(seq(0,12,length=1000), fit), 
                      x=seq(0,12,length=1000))

ggplot(densdf, aes(y=y,x=x))+geom_line()
```

Perhaps you were insisting on one with 2 degrees of freedom?

[image]

Comment: This looks even less accurate than the density plot in my question.

Comment: I plotted a distribution with three degrees of freedom. You plotted one with 2.